# Is non-sag mortar appropriate for large tile on walls?

Tags: tile, thinset

I am learning about thinsets and their use. As far as I can understand when it says large tiles it basically means no sag.

Now in my understanding a tile wont sag on the wall unless some horizontal pressure is applied somehow.

Then this raises the question: is there any other specific reason why I should buy Large tile thinset if I am installing the tiles on the wall?

Comment: Think by sag they mean it will not flow/sink downwards.

Comment: Yes you are right but the question still stands, the tile cant sag on a wall can it?

Comment: Large tiles are usually heavier tiles.  Unless you can slap a tile on a wall and it is an instant set, then there is a period of time where the weight of tiles might lead to sinking, unless supported(grout spacers?).  Most tiles don't sag(bend) well(break), if that is what you mean by sag.

Comment: I wont install toles on a wall without a bottom support wood strip for the first row and then solid spacers so I dont think that the mortar will help in any way

Comment: Also need to worry about tile peeling away from wall before full setting/attachment.  Don.t want to need to hold tiles to wall, when you could setting more tiles.

Comment: What do the instructions on the bag/pail say? Odds are good that there's an indication on whether it's suitable for use with large tiles on a vertical surface.

Comment: Here you go you can read yourself is you wish https://www.homedepot.ca/product/custom-building-products-versabond-lft-50-lb-gray-fortified-medium-bed-mortar/1000859845 Nothing about walls neither do nor don't use it

Comment: I think this is the right product for large tiles installed on the wall https://www.homedepot.ca/product/custom-building-products-flexbond-lft-crack-prevention-medium-bed-mortar-white-50-lb-/1000797773 
As far as I understand this at this moment there is two problems with large tiles: sagging and cracking 
this product probably covers the second case which could be a problem on the wall while sagging does not seem to happen there if you support the tiles from below with either a strip of wood for the first line or spaces for the next ones